# Touchpad scrolling reloading web pages

Tags: touchpad, browser, scrolling

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 Gnome classic. I'm using Firefox 13.0.1.

In my browser, while I use my touchpad to scroll up and down a page, previous web pages are simply being loaded again.

eg: If I visited abcd.com, and then visited xyz.com, while scrolling through xyz.com, suddenly abcd.com will be loaded in the same tab.

How can I disable this behavior of touchpad scrolling? Or is this a bug?

Comment: You should report a bug.

Comment: Which package might this bug be associated with?

Comment: Smooth scrolling isn't supposed to do that, so `firefox`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled the smooth scrolling option in firefox->preferences->advanced->browsing and the problem is not there anymore.

[image]